# How can Latexmk compile file that contains Chinese Characters in path in Windows 10?

Tags: luatex, windows, latexmk

I can use the following command in Windows without problem:

```
latexmk -lualatex -shell-escape "xxx.tex"
```

But if the filename contains Chinese character then it fails:

```
latexmk -lualatex -shell-escape "中文.tex"
```

I tried to change the default code page to 65001, it doesn't help. The only difference is that it now displays all the Chinese characters as blocks instead of some strange characters.

How to make it work?

The output is like the following(Notice the strange characters ����):

```
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 17 March 2019, version: 4.63b.
Latexmk: In reading rule 'lualatex' in 'c:/Users/Jeff/thesis2.0/����NodeJs�ĵ��̴���ϵͳ�����ʵ��.fdb_latexmk',
  destination has different name than configured...
Rule 'lualatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'chapter4/sku-lock-design.tex'
...
----------------------
C:\texlive\2019\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:907: command failed with exit code 12:
perl.exe c:\texlive\2019\texmf-dist\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl -lualatex -shell-escape -enable-write18 -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -outdir=c:/Users/Jeff/thesis2.0 -f ����NodeJs�ĵ��̴���ϵͳ�����ʵ��
```

Comment: Yes the Catalina works fine, I met the problem on Windows 10.

Comment: Which TeX system do you use? And does it compile if you use lualatex directly?

Comment: Could  you add to your question the output that latexmk gives, so we can see what the failure was, and what error messages resulted.  This is in addition to giving the result of running lualatex directly from the command line.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I use TexLive 2019, will try lualatex directly.

Comment: @JohnCollins, I'll paste the output later. Basically it says the file with the strange characters filename doesn't exist.

Comment: Texlive 2019 will be problematic. If I remember correctly proper support for such file names was added to luatex  in spring and so exists only in the texlive 2020 binaries. Either install it or get at least newer luahbtex from w32tex.org.

Comment: @JeffTian It may help you to know that there are several stages of processing between you typing the filename and lualatex receiving it.  That includes an invocation of cmd.exe by the Perl interpreter, which can lead to interesting problems. So it's important to see exactly where the problem is, which the detailed listing should help with.

Comment: @JohnCollins lualatex works for me, but latexmk fails, see my answer.

Comment: @JeffTian The error message on the last two lines indicates that latexmk returned exit code 12. In the source code of latexmk, I see that  that happens when there is a failure of some part of the processing by latexmk. To see what kind of error you've got, you need to look at the output from latexmk, which you've just indicated by dots. You should find relevant information, maybe even near the bottom. However, it looks like you are compiling a big document. It would be better to do the test on a **very** simple minimal document. Then error messages are easier to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct support for luatex for utf8 file names where added to texlive 2020 in may 2020. Before this it didn't work.

With a current texlive 2020 I can run file with chinese file names with lualatex without problems:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX)  (format=lualatex 2020.9.14)  19 SEP 2020 21:18
 restricted system commands enabled.
**中文.tex
(./中文.tex

...

Output written on 中文.pdf (1 page, 2891 bytes).
```

But `latexmk` fails:

```
C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\tests>latexmk -lualatex 中文.tex
Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 13 September 2020, version: 4.70a.
Latexmk: Filename '5%.tex' contains character not allowed for TeX file.
Latexmk: Stopping because of bad filename(s).
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing! Can you also share how to install texlive 2020 on windows 10? I refer to the official document and downloaded the .bat file and ran it. But after it completed successfully the tlmgr says it is still 2019 version.

Comment: You perhaps need to adjust the path variable.

Comment: The error message from latexmk has a filename that is not the one on the command line, but merely '5%.tex'.  This suggests that somewhere between cmd.exe and the actual execution of the latexmk script under perl.exe there was some mangling of the character string for the filename. The '5%.tex' was whatever latexmk.pl found in the command line passed to it.  (For what it's worth, on macOS latexmk works fine with chinese filenames at least as far back as TeXLive 2017.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The error message you obtained shows that latexmk didn't even try processing your file, because it received a bad filename.  But the listing in the question shows that latexmk did get further, and processed the file, but with an error. Perhaps your cmd.exe is using a different code page than the OP's.

Comment: @JohnCollins windows isn't easy, the fact that lualatex only works since a few month is proof enough. pdfcrop doesn't work for me too, and a short search shows that there are a number of pitfalls here, see e.g. https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1231890.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I can believe the difficulties.  My tests of latexmk with non-ASCII characters are only with those in some Western European languages (accented characters mostly).  Then it does work for me.

Comment: **Postscript**: Since the time of this question, I've worked out what's going on. Latexmk is a perl script, and when Windows is used with a default configuration, perl scripts don't support the full range of Unicode characters in filenames (but only the subset that Windows calls the ANSI code page). Even to support that limited set needs special treatment, which didn't happen in latexmk until v. 4.77 (dating from early 2022).   (N.B. There's no such problem with the other major operating systems, i.e., macOS and linux.)